# what is precise definition of proposition?

Tags: logic

What is precise definition of proposition (logic) ?
In the textbooks they define :

> "a declarative sentence that is either true 
>   or false."

But for me this definition is rather imprecise.
for example :
$x>2$
Is It a proposition? and why? in my idea $x>2$ Is't proposition ; because 
can be both true and false .

Comment: $x>2$ can't be both true and false simultaneously for the same real value of $x$.

Comment: $x>2$ is not a proposition because it involves a variable. To make it a proposition, we can either add a quantifier in front, or specify a value for the variable to take.

Comment: I guess if $x$ is already fixed, then $x>2$ is a proposition. For example: Let $x^2=5$ and $x>0$. Proposition: $x>2$. However $x>2$ on itself is probably not a proposition.

Comment: @SmileyCraft I agree that if $x$ is already fixed (say, replace it with the number $\pi$), then $x>2$ is a proposition. But I think the example you give has an implicit quantifier, and you're saying something like "for every $x$: if $x^2=5$ and $x>0$ then $x>2."

Comment: If you want a "formal" treatment, I suggest you look here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/ (especially sections 2 and 4).

Comment: Propositions are usually defined gramatically, and the exact grammar depends on which logic you are using.

Comment: See also the post [Formal definition of proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795307/formal-definition-of-proposition).